# JXA Applescript Getting Value of Slider

Tags: javascript, applescript, javascript-automation

I have a slider, and if I get `sliders()[0].value()`, it returns a totally wrong value.
I'm thinking something has to do with Value Indicator. However, `valueIndicator` doesn't show up in `sliders()[0].uiElements()` or `.entireContents()`.
How can I obtain the correct value of the slider? If you have to use value indicator, how do you obtain it using the value indicator with JavaScript?
Thanks!

Comment: Some code would be nice

Comment: I'm just getting regular slider from an ObjectSpecifier. I found that if I do sliders[0].attributes[2].value(), then I get the right value. sliders[0].attributes[2].name() is AXValueDescription. However, I can't do sliders[0].valueDescription(). Is there way to obtain the value without accessing the attributes array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened the Accessibility Inspector from xCode and looked at the slider that is causing the problem. The accessibility inspector showed all the attributes of the slider, and I found out that the slider.attributes["AXValueDescription"} had the right value.